# Scala Play Framework: Disable Browser Launch on localhost:9000 for Run Configuration

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, run-configuration

I feel like this should be simple but I can't find the answer anywhere. I'm trying to **disable** Play Framework from launching a browser window on `localhost:9000` when using a run configuration in Intellij when using `sbt Task` for the run configuration.

I know how to run a project on something other than the default port with `sbt run <my_port>`.

I can get the run configuration to launch a browser window with my custom port loaded automatically:

[Adding a task to launch a web browser on a specific port Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtjuA.png)

But I also want to disable the default behavior of launching a browser window with `localhost:9000`. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using a standard Play 2 run configuration, the first option on the edit run configuration dialog should be "Open in a browser after compilation". Disabling this will have the intended effect.

Comment: @ReganKoopmans you could have added your comment as an answer

Comment: We're using `sbt Task` for all of the run configurations, which have a different configuration dialog window unfortunately.

Comment: We figured it out, turns out it was another plugin we were using and not a setting in stock `Play!`